# Need explanation of weird syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, compound-literals

i follow tutorial and find this code:

```
self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size = image.size};
```

Its pretty clear What it does, but I'm not understand syntax of this line of code. First time i see something like this: `.size = image.size`. In dot syntax i expect to see something in front of dot, like `self.view`, but what is meaning of `.size`?

Second question is - why there is round brackets and after them curly brackets? I never seen structure like that `(){};` before.

My question may sound silly, but now I'm a bit confused, can someone provide explanation? Thank you.

Comment: I've never seen this either but FYI - `{}` are not square brackets, those are "curly braces". Square brackets are `[]` and the `()` are parentheses, not "round brackets".

Comment: This is syntax from C structs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Designated_initializers

Comment: Thank you dasdom, and thank you rmaddy, that was mistyping :)

Comment: Or you could simply do: `self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);`.

Comment: Thank you rmaddy, that is the way i use to do such things, for me it much more clearly for understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Designated Initializer syntax](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) of C structs. The parentheses `()` are used to cast the struct to a `CGRect`. As [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) points out, the cast is not necessary unless you use compound literal syntax, where you don’t name the parameters.

Comment: `CGRect frame = { .origin=..., .size=... }` would be a designated initializer (where you don't need the cast). `self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){ ... }` is an assigment where the rhs is a *compound literal* (and the cast is required).

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. I hope I interpreted it correctly in my edit.

Comment: @MartinR: Unless I'm very mistaken, the `{ .origin=… }` is the designated initializer syntax, and the `(CGRect){}` is the compound literal syntax. So this is both.